# How to control an app prototype on iphone/ipad from Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, prototype, voice, speech

I would like to create a prototype to show an app concept. It would be a voice-based cooking assistant, utilizing voice recognition.
User would speak to iPhone/iPad, and navigate through a recipe which would be spoken back to him. This prototype will be shown at student exhibition – there will be space to hide a mac, and possibility of connecting the iphone by cable to it as well.
I have no experience in XCode, I have some experience in programming and coding. I made some prototypes in flinto/invision, but I guess that for this project, native programming is a must - or am I wrong?
How hardcore would I need to go to be able to make this work?
Is there any way to fake it – for example use the voice detection in OS X/Web Speech Api in Chrome and make a webapp which would be streamed to iphone/ipad as to a secondary monitor?

Thank you for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "script", and follow it, you don't have to develop a functional app, just something able to show the concept.

There is a WWDC video to show some concepts of prototyping, highly recommended.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-223/

Comment: Thank you very much, you are hitting the nail on the head. I don't know why but I am always trying to push it too much on the functional side. I found out that I can use web speech api in chrome, and create this as an web app which would then be run & mirroed (Macbook->Iphone with transferring touch events) or run on android phone :) I just like the idea of people saying maybe one of the predefined phrases and getting a specific feedback in the "script". Thanks for your comment!